# Diffusion Equation pde well posed with Energy Method?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Given the [Enegry method found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem) I am trying to implement in the below diffusion partial differential equation in order to find the stability of the problem.Now let's say that the equation and Dirichlet conditions are the those as given below:

$$
{\displaystyle {\begin{cases}u_{t}-\kappa u_{xx}=0,0<x<1,\kappa >0,\\u(x,0)=f(x),\\u(0,t)=0,\\u(1,t)=0,\\\end{cases}}}
$$

As stated in the link in order to carry out the energy method for the problem, one would multiply the equation by
$u$ and integrate in space over the given interval.So :

\begin{align*}
u_{t} &= \kappa u_{xx} \\
uu_{t} &= \kappa uu_{xx} \\
 \partial_{t} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ u^{2} }{2}dx&=\kappa \int_{0}^{1} uu_{xx} dx\\
  \frac{1}{2}\partial _{t}\|u\|_{2}^{2}&=\kappa  \int_{0}^{1} u u_{xx}dx \\
 \partial _{t}\|u\|_{2}^{2}&=2\kappa  \int_{0}^{1} u u_{xx}dx \\
 \partial _{t}\|u\|_{2}^{2}&=-2\kappa  \int_{0}^{1} u^{2}_{x}dx \\
\end{align*}

1. Am I right ?
2. And if I am how can I continue from here ?
   [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem) it states that :

"Then one would integrate in time and one would obtain the energy estimate:
$$ \|u(\cdot ,t)\|_{2}\leq \|f(\cdot )\|_{2}"$$
And for the lhs is simple enough to understand.But I cannot understand the result in the rhs.

Comment: 1. Yes, you are right 2. Note that your last equality implies $\partial_{t} \| u \|_{2}^{2} \le 0$ i.e $u$ is non-increasing for all time (provided $\kappa > 0$), hence $$\| u(x,t) \|_{2}^{2} \le \| u(x,0) \|_{2}^{2} = \| f(x) \|_{2}^{2}$$

Comment: @mattos thanks mate for your verification